# FB.getLoginStatus not calling its callback

Tags: facebook, fbjs

The title really says it all.  Under some (undetermined) conditions FB.getLoginStatus() just stops working and won't invoke the callback I gave it.  The only interesting clues I've found are

- FB.Auth._loadState is stuck on "loading" -- whatever is supposed to make it click over to "loaded" isn't happening
- slight delays like putting in `alert()` calls tend to make it start working

Any hints at all about even how to investigate this welcome.

Comment: it happens reliably right after a user removed your application

Comment: I'm experiencing this too.  Do you get the Facebook login popup with a Facebook error message or is the popup not happening at all?  For me the popup as stopped working (and it's not being blocked - just not being called, no callback in JavaScript either).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This usually happens for me when I am running the page under a different domain from what has been registered in Facebook. Typically this is when I am developing locally.

If you are running locally, you'll have to set up a local web server and then modify your hosts file to point the the registered domain to 127.0.0.1 in order to test on your local machine. Don forget to remove that line from the hosts file when you want to test it on the server.

Comment: Yes yes yes! Finally.  I had created a facebook app ages ago, but didn't ever get around to changing the URL.  Shame on FB for not providing a useful error message.

Answer (score 12):

According to:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/240058389381072

You cannot put your application under sandbox mode, or else it won't work. Go into your app settings, advanced, and switch it. This stumped me for a couple hours until I happened upon the bug report.

Answer (score 12):

I had similar problem with FB API. It turned out, that my Facebook App was misconfigured. Please make sure that this is not the case for you. My problem was that my "**Site URL**" param in FB application was pointing to **https**, but I was using http protocol for development. Any call against FB api after `FB.init` was not calling my callback functions. So the first thing to do should be to double check App config.

Now, if some reason you depend on FB api but you wish to have a fallback option in case it;s inoperative - workaround with timer should be ok for you. Just set up a timer and disable it if FB Api gives you proper response. If not - fallback to some custom function which will perform some additional logic.

```js
 function callFbApi() {
    var timeoutHandler = setTimeout(function() { requestFailed(); }, 1000);

    function requestFailed() {
        // When this happens, it means that FB API was unresponsive
        doSomeFallbackWork();
        alert('hey, FB API does not work!');
    }

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutHandler); // This will clear the timeout in case of proper FB call
        doSomeUsualWorkAfterFbReplies();

        return false;
    }, true);
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you are using the asynchronous call. The same thing happened when I called FB.init with window.fbAsyncInit.  All I did was delay the FB.getLoginStatus with a setTimeout function

```js
  window.setTimeout(checkLogStatus, 1000);


  function checkLogStatus(){
          alert("check");
          // fetch the status on load      
          FB.getLoginStatus(handleSessionResponse);
  }
```

It seemed to work after that

Answer (score 6):

If your application is in sandbox mode, Facebook acts as if your application is invisible to anyone who is not listed as an application developer. If you're not logged in, then it would stand to reason that your app is now invisible.

The callback will only fire if you're initializing with a visible application. Otherwise the following response is returned:

```
<span>Application Error: There was a problem getting data for the application you requested. The application may not be valid, or there may be a temporary glitch. Please try again later. </span>
```

For more info please see my comment on this bug ticket:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/240058389381072

Answer (score 1):

On the new version of the Developer app, you have to make sure to have put the correct URL you are using to access the application in the *Website* field under the

*Select how your app integrates with Facebook*

section.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the protocol is **HTTPS** and not HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The site worked every time when I was opening the browser, but fails when I tried to reload.

The cause was the missing "www" on the site name on Facebook configurations. Note that putting "www" (like www.yoursite.com) works on both situations (yoursite.com or www.yoursite.com).

Answer (score 0):

As others have posted, you must be accessing your site at the same URL that facebook expects.  For example if facebook has a callback "example.com" but you're browser has "www.example.com", that can cause this problem.

In addition, if third-party cookies are not allowed by your browser, you may also see this problem.  Or you may see the callback [erroneously reporting the user is not connected](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/173032012783482).

Answer (score 0):

Just posting a situation I had were calling `FB.getLoginStatus` got absolutely no response.

My application is designed to run in a tab, and I only entered the **Page Tab** URLs on the app admin page, and not the **App On Facebook** (i.e. Canvas) URLs. The tab loads perfectly, but any calls to the FB JS SDK provoke no response.

Answer (score -1):

In Facebook App Settings, go to **Client OAuth Settings**, look at **Valid OAuth redirect URIs**

Make sure you have listed all URIs which are the domains from which Facebook SDK is being invoked. For example:

[image]

I develop at localhost:5000 and deploy to Heroku. Notice the format: `http://domain.name/`

Comment: No any Client OAuth settings